# Android: Send E-Mail with multiple Mimetypes "HTML & PLAINTEXT"

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent, plaintext

How can i send multiple mime types email with Android?

Intent.setType allows only one mimetype.
I want to send an email with HTML & PLAINTEXT.

Has anybody any solution of my problem?

Comment: Are you wish to sent a Multimedia content?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i send multiple mime types email with Android?

You would need to use JavaMail or some similar library that perhaps allows multiple email attachments.